# Spring Data REST - RepositoryEventHandler methods not getting invoked for POST method?

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, spring-data, spring-data-rest

I have the following domain object and DTO defined.

**Country.java**

```
@Data
@Entity
public class Country extends ResourceSupport {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    private long countryID;

    @NotBlank(message = "Country name is a required field")
    private String countryName;

    private String countryNationality;
}
```

**CountryDTO.java**

```
@Data

public class CountryDTO {

    private List<Country> countries;
}
```

I have overridden the POST method in the RepositoryRestController for the country class.

```
@RepositoryRestController
public class CountryController {

    @Autowired
    private CountryRepository repo;

    @RequestMapping(method = POST, value = "countries")
    public @ResponseBody ResponseEntity<?> createCountry(@RequestBody Resource<CountryDTO> dto,
            Pageable page, PersistentEntityResourceAssembler resourceAssembler) {

        Country savedCountry = repo.save(dto.getContent().getCountries());
        return new ResponseEntity<>(resourceAssembler.toResource(savedCountry), HttpStatus.OK);
    }


}
```

Now I have defined a RepositoryEventHandler to handle validations.

```
@Component
@RepositoryEventHandler
public class CountryHandler {


    @HandleBeforeCreate
    public void handleBeforeCreate(Country country) {

        System.out.println("testing");

}
```

But when I send a POST request to the endpoint `http://localhost:8080/countries`, the eventhandler does not get invoked. Is there anything I am doing wrong?

UPDATE 1:
I am sending the following JSON to the endpoint using Postman.

```
"countries":[{
    "countryName":"Australia",
    "countryNationality":"Australian"

}]
```

Comment: How are you invoking a POST on that URL?

Comment: I am sending a JSON through Postman

Answer (score 0):

It is difficult to give you an exact solution not knowing how you are invoking the request. But possible reason is that you are missing the slash symbol `@RequestMapping` value attribute:

```
@RequestMapping(method = POST, value = "countries")
```

Should be:

```
@RequestMapping(method = POST, value = "/countries")
```

Comment: you can ask for info you need using comments

Comment: I have updated the question with the JSON I am sending to the endpoint

Comment: Ok, did you try to put slash in RequestMapping value as I had proposed?

Answer (score 0):

Define a Bean in AppConfigration as

```
@Configuration
@EnableAsync
public class AppConfig {

  @Bean
    CountryHandler countryHandler (){
        return new CountryHandler ();
    }

}
```

It will work then.

Answer (score 0):

Try editing maybe  the Controller class annotation from:

```
@RepositoryRestController
```

to

```
@RestController
```

and mainly the method annotation from:

```
@RequestMapping(method = POST, value = "countries")
```

to

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/countries", method = RequestMethod.POST, produces = MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_VALUE)
```

PS: `produces = MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_VALUE` if you are going to return json.

Comment: If I change to @RestController my controller class will be out of Spring Data Rest scope and I will have to implement GET, PUT and DELETE methods as well

Comment: I do not think so. `Open Declaration org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RestController`. You can have `@RestController` with `@RequestMapping(value = "/countries", method = RequestMethod.POST)` for sure. I am not sure what you mean by implementing another GET PUT DELETE methods ? For Rest controllers I have always used those two annotations for the class and the method and I have never had any problems invoking a method or else. (Of course when we are talking about Spring not `Open Declaration javax.ws.rs.*` )

Comment: I am using Spring Data Rest so there is actually no need to implement a controller. Spring does that at runtime. But since I am using a DTO I have to implement a POST method.

Answer (score 0):

I know this is older but this works as it is supposed to.

The methods defined in a `@RepositoryRestController` implementation replace the methods in the default [RepositoryEntityController](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-data-rest/blob/master/spring-data-rest-webmvc/src/main/java/org/springframework/data/rest/webmvc/RepositoryEntityController.java) which publish `@RepositoryEventHandler` events.

So your controller needs to publish a create event:

```
@RepositoryRestController
public class CountryController {

    @Autowired
    private CountryRepository repo;

    private final ApplicationEventPublisher publisher; //This changed

    @RequestMapping(method = POST, value = "countries")
    public @ResponseBody ResponseEntity<?> createCountry(@RequestBody Resource<CountryDTO> dto,
            Pageable page, PersistentEntityResourceAssembler resourceAssembler) {

        Country savedCountry = repo.save(dto.getContent().getCountries());
        publisher.publishEvent(new BeforeCreateEvent(savedCountry)); //This changed
        return new ResponseEntity<>(resourceAssembler.toResource(savedCountry), HttpStatus.OK);
    }


}
```